# Корректность реализации конструкторов

Tags: c++, конструктор

Попробовал реализовать основные виды конструкторов для класса. Хочу убедится что все сделано правильно, на мой взгляд всё корректно.Есть ли здесь ошибки?

```
class resource {};


class storage
{
    public:
        storage() = default;
        explicit storage(resource* res) : resource_{res} {}

        storage(const storage& source) {
          resource_= new resource;
          this->resource_ = source.resource_;
        }

        storage& operator=(const storage& source) {
          storage tmp(std::move(source));
          std::swap(*this, tmp);
          return *this;
        }

        storage(storage&& source) {
          resource_ = source.resource_;
          source.resource_ = nullptr;
        }

        storage& operator=(storage&& source) {
          storage tmp(std::move(source));
          std::swap(*this, tmp);
          return *this;
        }

        ~storage() {
          delete resource_;
          resource_ = nullptr;
        }

    private:
        resource* resource_ = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Возможна утечка: `storage& operator=(const storage& source)` т.к. вы просто переписываете указатель.

Comment: Вот в `storage(const storage& source)` - действительно утечка.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> storage() = default;
> ```

Подойдет.

---

> ```
> explicit storage(resource* res) : resource_{res} {}
> ```

Подойдет, если подразумевается, что ваш класс берет на себя владение ресурсом.

Оба этих конструктора можно было свести в один

```
explicit storage(resource* res = nullptr) : resource_{res} 
  {}
```

---

> ```
> storage(const storage& source) {
>     resource_= new resource;
>     this->resource_ = source.resource_;
>   }
> ```

Здесь написана какая-то белиберда. Утечка памяти. И почему в одной строке `resource_`, а в следующей внезапно `this->resource_`? Это ведь одно и то же.

Возможно подразумевалось

```
storage(const storage &source) 
{
  if (source.resource_ != nullptr)
  {
    resource_= new resource;
    *resource_ = *source.resource_;
  }
}
```

Не забываем про возможность `source.resource_ == nullptr`.

Лучше

```
storage(const storage &source) 
{ 
  if (source.resource_ != nullptr)
    resource_ = new resource{*source.resource_}; 
}
```

или

```
storage(const storage &source) :
    resource_{source.resource_ != nullptr ? 
      new resource{*source.resource_} : nullptr}
  {}
```

---

> ```
> storage& operator=(const storage& source) {
>     storage tmp(std::move(source));
>     std::swap(*this, tmp);
>     return *this;
>   }
> ```

Опять какая-то белиберда. Чего вы пытаетесь достичь, применяя `std::move` к константной ссылке? Это бессмысленно.

Поэтому

```
storage &operator =(const storage &source) 
{
  if (this == &source)
    return *this;

  storage tmp{source};

  using std::swap;
  swap(*this, tmp); 

  return *this;
}
```

Без проверки на самоприсваивание код будет работать корректно, но не оптимально (лишние копирования). Возможно это и не проблема, ибо самоприсваивание - обычно экзотическая ситуация.

Обратите также внимание на опасность бесконечной рекурсии в вызове `swap(*this, tmp)`, если будет вызван именно `std::swap` и в классе нет отдельного перемещающего оператора присваивания. Безопаснее будет `std::swap(this->resource_, tmp.resource_)`.

---

> ```
> storage(storage&& source) {
>     resource_ = source.resource_;
>     source.resource_ = nullptr;
>   }
> ```

Либо так, либо

```
storage(storage &&source) 
  { std::swap(resource_, source.resource_); }
```

либо

```
storage(storage &&source) : resource_{source.resource_}
  { source.resource_ = nullptr; }
```

---

> ```
>  storage& operator=(storage&& source) {
>      storage tmp(std::move(source));
>      std::swap(*this, tmp);
>      return *this;
>    }
> ```

Что это за белиберда? Зачем вдруг понадобилось создавать объект `tmp`???

И что произойдет, если изнутри `std::swap` вызовется перемещающий оператор присваивания (а он оттуда вызывается)? Произойдет бесконечная рекурсия.

Поэтому

```
storage &operator =(storage &&source) 
{
  std::swap(this->resource, source.resource);
  return *this;
}
```

Однако (!), учитывая, что ваш класс имеет очень маленький размер, т.е. состоит из одного указателя, можно вообще не писать отдельную копирующую и отдельную перемещающую версию оператора присваивания. Можно написать одну версию на все случаи жизни

```
storage &operator =(storage source) 
{
  std::swap(this->resource_, source.resource_);
  return *this;
}
```

Параметр передается именно по значению. Такой вариант прекрасно и эффективно покроет и задачи копирования, и задачи перемещения таких объектов. Определенным недостатком такого варианта является невозможность добавления проверки на самоприсваивание. При этом код имеет корректное, но неоптимальное поведение при самоприсваивании.

---

Выше я периодически говорю, что вместо `std::swap(*this, source)` якобы лучше делать `std::swap(this->resource, source.resource);`. Здесь надо добавить некоторые уточнения.

В рамках "классической" реализации copy-and-swap идиомы вполне допускается (и, в общем случае, даже *лучше*) выполнять именно `swap(*this, source)`, но для этого ваш класс *обязательно* (!) должен обладать своей собственной реализацией функции `swap`, которая обычно объявляется как friend

```
friend void swap(storage &lhs, storage &rhs)
{
  ...
}
```

Эта функция должна выполнять непосредственный обмен содержимого объектов через обмен индивидуальных полей, и не в коем случае не делегировать вызов в `std::swap(lhs, rhs)`. Вызывать ее, разумеется, надо именно как `swap`, а не как `std::swap`.

Только так вы сможете защититься от опасности неожиданно устроить бесконечную рекурсию при использовании варианта `swap(*this, source)`.

---

Над всем над этим реет призрак некоей недоговоренности.... Что это за странный класс такой? С одной стороны, конструктор `explicit storage(resource* res)` предполагает, что выделением памяти для ресурса занимается вызывающий код. С другой - сам класс тоже активно занимается выделением памяти для ресурса при копировании.

Может быть лучше тогда все вопросы выделения/освобождения памяти решать строго внутри этого класса? Конструктор `explicit storage(resource* res)` убрать, а вместо него сделать конструкторы

```
explicit storage(const resource &res) : resource_{new resource{res}}
  {}

explicit storage(resource &&res) : resource_{new resource{std::move(res)}}
  {}
```

?

Другой вариант - наоборот, оставить конструктор `explicit storage(resource* res)` и полностью возложить ответственность за выделение памяти на внешний код, а внутри этого класса память не выделять вообще никогда. Копирование объектов данного класса запретить вообще, а оставить только перемещение (т.е. аналогично тому, как работает, `std::unique_ptr`).

У вас же наблюдается какой-то гибрид из этих двух подходов...

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ)